# How to write insertion sort

Tags: c++, sorting

could someone explain why this is not working?
For example, if I have this array: 3 4 1 2 55 32 1111 53 
the output is going to be 3 3 3 4 32 53 55 1111. 
Thanks!

```
void insertionSort(int arr[], int len) {
int i, j, tmp;
for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    tmp = arr[i];
    for (j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
        if (arr[j] > tmp) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        }
        else {
            arr[j + 1] = tmp;
            break;
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: Debugger.  Use a debugger.  A debugger will allow you to single step through your program *watching* values in variables.  Using a debugger is often faster than posting correctly to StackOverflow and *waiting* for somebody to inspect your code or debug it for you.  Please edit your post with the text of your debugging session.

Comment: Off the top, you never ever assign to `arr[0]`. That can't be right.

Comment: For best results, fashion a [mcve]. You should do this with or without a Stack Overflow question in mind as the act of isolating the problem to produce the MCVE very often reveals the cause in all its buggy glory.

Comment: I tried to debug it but I do not know where the problem is ... If I change the second for loop with a while loop it works. But I was wondering why this is not working.

Comment: "Why doesn't this work?" is not a good question. It does not work because the algorithm you wrote does not do what you intended. It does what you wrote.

Comment: @puls99 *I tried to debug it but I do not know where the problem is .* -- That should never happen if you write your own programs.  When you wrote the program, you had a plan in mind and hopefully, you wrote the plan down on paper.  You took the plan, wrote a program following the plan, and now the  program goes against the plan that you wrote. When that happens, you debug each step to see where the program deviates from the plan you had.  If you just copied and pasted from a site, and then asked one of us to debug when your program doesn't work, that is worthy of a downvote.

Comment: I wrote it myself. I read a pseudo-code on how it should work and I also watched a visualization of the sorting algorithm and I came up with this code. I also searched for implementations of it and each one used a while-loop instead of a for-loop. In my mind, the while-loop and the for-loop were the same but that was not the case. I tried to print the variables to see what was wrong but my mind was focused on why the for cannot be used here. I should have used a proper debugging as you said.I will follow your advice when learning new algorithms and I will start by writing them on paper.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you posted is not a true translation of the Wikipedia pseudo code.

```
void insertion_sort(int arr[], const int len) {
    for (int i = 1; i < len; ++i) {
        int x = arr[i];
        int j = i-1;
        while((j >= 0)&&(arr[j] > x)) {
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            j = j-1;
        }
        arr[j+1] = x;
   }
}
```

Welcome to StackOverlow. Before you post another question, please read all the links about [Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).  Pay particular attention to the one about [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you also tell me where my "translation" went wrong? I am really curious. Can the while loop be written as a for loop? I am trying to learn new algorithms and I would appreciate very much if you could tell me what is wrong.

Comment: Try this. Implement both algorithms, insertion_sort and bad_insertion_sort. Step though each in a debugger using the same input. Notice where they diverge.